# How do i change the default primary key in django?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm new to learning django. I'm using PostgreSQL as my database. I created an app called gplus and a model I created looks something like this

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  date_of_birth = models.DateTimeField()
```

I applied the migrations and then wanted to change the primary key field from default 'id' to 'username'. So, in the psql command line I ran the following commands

```
ALTER TABLE gplus_account DROP CONSTRAINT gplus_account_pkey;
ALTER TABLE gplus_account ADD PRIMARY KEY (username);
ALTER TABLE gplus_account DROP COLUMN id;
```

Then in the models.py, I edited the username field as

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=true)
```

Now, when I try to apply the migrations, I get the error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "id" of relation "gplus_account" does not exist
```

It seems Django needs to know there is no 'id' field in the table anymore. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Making the username the PK is a bad idea. The PK should be unrelated to your data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you elaborate why? I searched online and the only criteria I found for assigning primary key to a field was that each data in the field should be unique.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should avoid going into your psql DB and running any commands. Mostly everything you'll need to do should be possible through django's interfaces. For example, here you want to update the schema of the DB. To do this you need to 1) make the change to the models.py and then 2) run the migration.

In this case, the change you need to make is to set the username field to be the primary key, this is accomplished, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#field-options) by using the option for primary_key to true:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, primary_key=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  date_of_birth = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now that you have the updated code representation of the model, You need to tell Django to update the actual DB to reflect this. This is fairly straightforward (docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#workflow)). The steps are to go to the command line where your manage.py is and run the two following commands in order:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: ok, this tells me how to update the schema and I'll use it the next time I need to do an update. But how can I fix my condition? Do I need to add the id field again from the psql command line? Or better yet, is there a way to let Django know I'm not using the id field anymore?